# C#: Cannot send email via smpt.office365.com

Tags: c#, .net, office365

Ok, I've read tons of posts about this topic, still it doesn't work. I'm trying to send email via the smpt server of office365. Of course I checked the credentials logging in from the browser.

```
smtpClient.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
smtpClient.Port = 587;
smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password, "MicrosoftOffice365Domain.com");
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
smtpClient.TargetName = "STARTTLS/smtp.office365.com";
```

I get an exception and the emails are not sent:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' in System.dll
>   Failure sending mail. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to
>   the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A
>   connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
>   respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to respond xx.xxx.xx.x:587    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress)    at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream,
>   Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket,
>   Socket& abortSocket6)    at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object
>   owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)    at
>   System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject,
>   GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)    at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint
>   servicePoint)    at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()    at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)

Is there something other I need to add in the configuration?

### UPDATE

After rebooting something has changed. Now it actually connects with the server but this time I get this exception:

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

Why does it say the email is "anonymous"?

I set the `FROM` field to the same email address used for the authentication.

Comment: This seems to be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30342884/the-server-response-was-5-7-57-smtp-client-was-not-authenticated-to-send-anony

Comment: Here the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31289772/881712 the UseDefaultCredential goes first!

Comment: Ops, sorry, I didn't see your comment before posting mine. Should I close this question?