# Error Sending Mail - The server response was:5.7.57 SMTP, Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, authentication

while sending Email for ForgotPassword in my application i'm getting this Error.

```
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; 
Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [XXXXXXXXXX.xxxxxxxxx.prod.outlook.com]
```

i referred following Links and Solutions

[5-7-57-smtp-client-was-not-authenticated-to-send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30342884/the-server-response-was-5-7-57-smtp-client-was-not-authenticated-to-send-anony/31289772)

[The-server-response-was-SMTP-Client-was-not-authen](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/993859/The-server-response-was-SMTP-Client-was-not-authen)

[5757-smtp-client-was-not-authenticated-to-send-anonymous-mail-during-mail-from](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1738cae2-4e04-4875-9d91-dac6516c5696/error-5757-smtp-client-was-not-authenticated-to-send-anonymous-mail-during-mail-from-from?forum=Office365forDevelopers)

i tried changing the port, Added Domain along with Credentials, Changed `client.UseDefaultCredentials` to false and placed above `credentials`.

still getting this same error every time and no solutions helped.

please suggest if anyone have the solution.

Thank you.

Comment: you need to set the annonymous setting for current email address

Comment: current email as in `From` or  `To` address? and anonymous settings means exactly can you explain?