# The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 Client was not authenticated to send

Tags: c#-4.0

The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail from [MN2PR15CA0026.namprd15.prod.outlook.com].

I am getting above error when trying to use mail server as : smtp.office365.com. It is working fine for other mail server .

Please suggest some solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [5.7.57 SMTP - Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30342884/5-7-57-smtp-client-was-not-authenticated-to-send-anonymous-mail-during-mail-fr)

Comment: Seems to be duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30342884/5-7-57-smtp-client-was-not-authenticated-to-send-anonymous-mail-during-mail-fr